# Why does paperclip uploaded image is not been displayed on rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was able to upload an image with paperclip. 
I am now trying to show that image

```
<%= image_tag @profile.image.url %>
```

this renders

```
<img alt="Missing" src="/images/original/missing.png?1379966496">
```

And nothing is been displayed. 
What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

In the model for profile be sure that you added:

```
attr_accessible :image
```

Paperclip will upload the file, but you need to whitelist it for it to be used in the view

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to edit this in a form?  I had the same problem, but by having the following code in my

```
app/views/product(your resource name)/_form.html.erb
```

file fixed it:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :avatar%><br>
  <%= f.file_field :avatar %> 
</div>
```